# Problema para calcular números curiosos con PHP

Tags: php

Números curiosos: Un número es curioso si sus dígitos cumplen estrictamente esta condición.

> “El número ubicado en la posición N+1 es múltiplo o divisor del
> predecesor ubicado en la posición N. En caso de que el predecesor sea
> 0, debe ser reemplazado por 1”

Por ejemplo, 2428 es curioso porque 4 es múltiplo de 2, 2 es divisor de 4 y 8 es múltiplo de 2.

**Datos de entrada:** Se recibe un parámetro con el número entero N > 10 (lo cual se debe validar)

**Datos de salida:** El programa debe imprimir por pantalla en una línea, conteniendo si es curioso o no y un único número: la cantidad de términos hasta que se rompió la condición de curioso o la totalidad de términos si se cumplió que es un número curioso.

> **Ejemplo1:** Entrada: 248 - Salida: Es curioso, 3 
> **Ejemplo2:** Entrada: 248257 - Salida: No es curioso, 4

Tengo que hacer este ejercicio peo no se como encararlo.

Comment: Tienes que hacer ese ejercicio.. en PHP... Y no sabes como encararlo ?? Supondré que estás estudiando entonces... Empieza a hacer al menos la primera parte de la oración !!!

Comment: En datos de entrada, te está pidiendo un ingreso de datos con `N > 10`... tampoco has hecho eso ??

Comment: Saludos. Es necesario coloques el código que realizaste; en dado caso el error que te muestra o el resultado erroneo (con datos fijos -escenario controlado- que resultada y cual debe ser); así se te puede guiar. La intención es ayudarte a resolver el problema no el resolvertelo. Siempre acompaña lo que necesitas con código y entradas asi como salidas que obtienes.

Answer (score 0):

Al margen de que quieras hacer un copia pega o pretendas aprender con ello y sin ningún ánimo de dejarte todo hecho, sino con la intención de que revises el ejercicio y "juegues" con él, he resuelto el problema:

```
<?php

$int = (string) 10840;
$n = strlen($int);
$curioso = true;

$paso = 0;
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<$n;$j++){
        if($j > $i){
            $primer_valor = $int[$i] ? $int[$i] : 1;
            $segundo_valor = $int[$j] ? $int[$j] : 1;
    
            $mayor = max($primer_valor,$segundo_valor);
            $menor = min($primer_valor,$segundo_valor);
    
            $paso++;
            if($mayor % $menor){
                $curioso = false;
                break(2);
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump($curioso);
var_dump($paso);
```

El planteamiento no es difícil:

- Al tener que comparar cada elemento con los demás implica que vas a tener que hacer dos bucles anidados.
- A partir de ahí, sólo se trata de hacer cumplir las condiciones que has impuesto:
- Si un elemento vale 0, se transforma en un 1.
- Si el mayor de los elementos no es divisible entre el menor de los elementos, no es curioso.
- Para saber si la condición de divisibilidad se cumple o no, declaras una variable a *true* y en el caso de que no se cumpla dicha condición, le asignas *false* y sales de los bucles.
- Para el contador, no tienes más que declarar una variable que te de el número de pasos y aumentarla en una unidad previo a la consulta de divisibilidad, ya que independientemente de que se cumpla o no, "el paso se ha dado".